# How is it possible that this question has a (deleted) answer with a lower post ID?

Tags: support, meta, stack-exchange-history, post-id

Archaeological question. When looking for the oldest question on Meta, I found that

> ["https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5)

redirects to

> ["https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-stackoverflow-support-more-than-2-openids-per-account/5#5"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-stackoverflow-support-more-than-2-openids-per-account/5#5)

None of the answers I see has a post number of 5, which means that that answer was deleted. But **how is it possible that the answer has a lower post ID than the question?**

At first I thought that the asker might have answered the question when posting it (using the "Answer your own question" checkbox), but I tried that and the answer is assigned ID *questionID* + 1. So that can't be why.

Similar: [Back to the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/back-to-the-future) (but not the same issue, since in that case the post IDs are in the expected order).

Comment: 6? It redirects to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sync-meta-user-accounts-daily-with-other-family-sites/5#5` for me... The answer with ID 5 is an answer to the question with ID 2. I don't see any reason why you'd be getting to the question with ID 6. It should just display a "this question was voluntarily removed by its author" message, because that's exactly what happened. *Edit:* Tested in a browser where I wasn't logged in, that's what happens. I have no IDea how you got to ID 6.

Comment: @animuson: Now it's redirecting me to #2 (deleted) as you see. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a weird post. It's written like an answer and is signed as "answered"...

[image]

...but if you aren't redirected it's displayed as a standalone question but without a title, a star button, or any views. It isn't a question though, when I send a fake request to favourite it I get this response:

[image]

Huh. It looks like the result of some error. Maybe the same thing is causing that behaviour for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has been fixed now, as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5 now redirects to the proper page which is question #2 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sync-meta-user-accounts-daily-with-other-family-sites/5#5

Question with ID 2 simply has an answer with ID 5 and this is totally normal.

Can't see any reason why https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5 redirected you to the wrong question page - hopefully some dev can explain.